# DB Connection Error in ASP.NET Core WebSite after initial Successful Connection

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, asp.net-core

We are running an Asp.NET Core Website in VS 2015 Update 3 our DB code is Async ADO.NET methods connecting to a SQL Server 10.50.1600.1 DB.

We are getting a strange DB authentication error when connecting to our DB.  The first time we run the web site everything works fine DB calls work perfectly.  Subsequent restarts also work fine as long as no website code is changed and needs recompiling such as making a change to a WebApi controller.  If this happens we get the error below and the only way to connect to the DB again is to restart the whole computer.  Restarting VS makes no difference.  We are using Kestrel not IIS.  This is driving us nuts we have to restart our machines several times a day. Would appreciate any suggestions!

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

Comment: This isn't an authentication error, it's telling you that the server you are trying to connect to doesn't exist or is not accessable. Are you sure your connection strings are correct, the SQL Server is still running and you're not doing anything odd with your DI setup? Not much else anyone can do to help without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi David.  Yeah nothing wrong with connection string or DB as it all works perfectly after a reboot then it just stops.

Comment: With regards to DB code its straight up ADO.NET Async code definitely not cause of the issue boiler plate straight from MSDN examples and it works first time.  It's almost as though Kestral is not using my user account to make DB connections once it recompiles code but it does the first time.

Comment: Yes but is the database still running?

Comment: Hi David, yes DB 100% still running we have an ASP.NET Project running from Visual Studio on IIS with exactly the same code on exactly the same DB at the same time and we don't have any issues.  We are fairly confident this is either a configuration issue or bug with ASP.NET Core/Kestral.